# Find and replace only in one cell

Tags: general-utilities

I would like to "find" and "replace all" in only one cell. Is this possible? 
For instance if I have an expression common to many cells, and I want to avoid having to replace it also in other cells, how would I "find &replace all" it without having to worry about other cells?

Is there a way to add a button on ctr+F panel?

Comment: The cheapest solution is to copy the cell to another notebook :) . I think you can make the question a bit more specific, for example, what do you need? A function e.g. `replaceInPreviousCell[a->b]`? A panel for this task? Or even a new button in the Ctrl+F panel ?

Comment: Your final suggestions are all very much suggestive! But your first one is definitely convincing. :)

Comment: Put a cursor before the cell -> find next -> replace and find next untill outside the cell.

Comment: @Kuba this is what I would like to avoid. My cell is enormous...

Comment: I see, do you want a general solution or do you want to replace specific symbol? Like `myFunction` and not e.g. `whatever[expression, {could be there}]`

Comment: I think it is the second case. I have to replace the state variables in a feedback law. As you know (I know you do! :) ), the state variables are thus written in that funny manner with the two dots above and below. To understand the history of the feedback law I have to substitute the output states in it. Things get pretty annoying when the feedback law is enormously long and nonlinear. @Kuba